# Does ASP.NET implicitly validate control with known values

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a checkboxlist with some items that have a value parameter set to a dataset filter.  Are these values validated on postback to make sure that they are within the range of valid checkboxes or can a user inject an invalid checkbox into the list with a harmful (sql injection) value.

Comment: I would _never_ trust input from the client side and _always_ validate on the server side.

Comment: This is the obvious answer, but ASP.NET should handle data coming from it's own controls specifically ones that don't (shouldn't) permit user modification such as a check box or radio button.  I've tested it at it appears to ignore requests with invalid data but I would like a link to some official documentation on it's handling before I trust it or write my own check box validation.

Comment: Why should it? It this kind of a law? I think, just because _I_ want something, doesn't mean that is _has to be_ a standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user can inject anything he wants on a page that's already rendered on his browser; however, the actual values associated to the checkboxes in the list will be encoded in the `ViewState`. The `ViewState` in turn is hashed (by default, at least) and therefore, the only way for someone to manipulate the value posted back to the server by one of the checkboxes is by manipulating the `ViewState` which will throw an exception immediately.

With that said, hashing is not infallible and you should take measures to ensure that the ViewState hasn't been tampered with. For example, you can also [encrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the ViewState to make it even more difficult but it will incur a performance penalty.

I would simply validate the value programmatically before allowing it to be used. Borrowing from Uwe's words above, *never trust user input*.